# Display Image in list View with using ImageLoader once time

Tags: android, image

I've code to display image in list view using imageLoader library from com.nostra13.universalimageloader

this code like this

```
imageLoader.displayImage(link_url, imageView, options, animateFirstListener);
```

but this code make this app must download image from this url. I wanna ask , can I using this cache image to show image. So if not connect internet the image can be show because this image was save as cache before?? How to show image in imageview if this image is from cache?? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of downloading it again you should cache images in phone memory or sdcard.

It caches images in say sdcard (if you have configured properly) using url as the key. If present display from cache else download, cache and display images.

In your custom adapter constructor

```
 File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(activity context, "cache_folder")
 imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

 ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(a)
.discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))
.discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
.enableLogging()
.build();

imageLoader.init(config);
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
.showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_id)//display stub image untik image is loaded
.cacheInMemory()
.cacheOnDisc()
.displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
.build();
```

In your getView()

```
viewholder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageview); 
imageLoader.displayImage(imageurl, viewholder.image,options);
```

Answer (score 2):

By deafult it stores cache i guess.

Check once Disconnecting internet.

```
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showStubImage(R.drawable.deafaultimage).cacheInMemory()
                .cacheOnDisc().bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
```

Comment: i know , but how to show image in image view from cache android?? I just know to show image from bitmap , thanks

Comment: yup , so? what I must to do?

Comment: i am using same thing in my app.
i am not doing anything to cache the image than this.
it is working for me.
so i am sugesting you the same

Answer (score 0):

HTTP caching depends on [Cache-Control headers](http://condor.depaul.edu/dmumaugh/readings/handouts/SE435/HTTP/node24.html). If the server is sending the proper headers in the response then the library will automatically cache the resource automatically and access it even if there is no network. You don't have to do anything explicitly.

You can configure more options such as cache size etc if you want. See the [docs](http://www.intexsoft.com/blog/item/72-universal-image-loader-part-2.html).